# Slowly moving gameobject to mouse position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to change the position of the object to the position of the mouse, moving slowly from first to second position.

My object is moving slowly to the random direction which appears to be connected with lower-left corner. When I go higher than the corner my object is moving upwards, same with left and right.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Rocket : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 10f;

    private Vector3 shippos;

    void Start()
    {
        shippos = transform.position;
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (Input.mousePosition.x > shippos.x)
            shippos.x=shippos.x+speed*Time.deltaTime;
        if (Input.mousePosition.x < shippos.x)
            shippos.x=shippos.x-speed*Time.deltaTime;
        if (Input.mousePosition.y > shippos.y)
            shippos.y=shippos.y+speed*Time.deltaTime;
        if (Input.mousePosition.y < shippos.y)
            shippos.y=shippos.y-speed*Time.deltaTime;
        transform.position = shippos;
    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to be asking 3 different questions. It also also not entirely clear what you are trying to achieve among these three. Can you please edit your question so that it is clear what you need help accomplishing.

Comment: @ryemoss Edited, maybe now it's more clear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mouse position is returned in screenspace coordinates. What you need to do is convert this to world coordinates so that they are compared in the same coordinate space as the transform (shippos).

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).x > shippos.x)
        shippos.x = shippos.x + speed * Time.deltaTime;
    if (Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).x < shippos.x)
        shippos.x = shippos.x - speed * Time.deltaTime;
    if (Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).y > shippos.y)
        shippos.y = shippos.y + speed * Time.deltaTime;
    if (Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).y < shippos.y)
        shippos.y = shippos.y - speed * Time.deltaTime;
    transform.position = shippos;
}
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks for explanation about screenspace to world coordinates conversion.

Answer (score 0):

If I did not misunderstand, you want to change your player's position straight to the point of mouse's position and looking towards mouse.

```
void Update() {
    Transform target = mousePosition; //get your mouse position per frame
    Vector3 relativePos = target.position - transform.position; //create a vector3 between them
    Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(relativePos); //then give a rotation your player towards this vector.
    transform.rotation = rotation; //and apply it.
}
```

Comment: Nothing in the question or OP's code mentions anything about rotation (and your code does not move any gameobject)

Comment: I want to move it slowly, not by teleporting to other position (I want continuous movement to direction of the mouse)

Answer (score 0):

Taken from here: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/633873/how-to-make-an-object-move-towards-the-mouse-point.html

```
public float moveSpeed = 2.0;  // Units per second

 void Update () {
         var targetPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
         targetPos.z = transform.position.z;
         transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPos, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
     }
```

May not be accurate C#, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

i guess you are doing wrong , because wile you have **[Mathf.Lerp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Lerp.html)** you Dont need to go as that clumsy way
Here is a video tutorial from youtube for **[mathf.lerp](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cD-mXwSCvWc)**

and here is the base code:

```
someValue = Mathf.Lerp(initialValue , finalValue , Time.deltaTime * smoothness);
```

just take a look to the youtube link you will definitely get the idea!

**AS A SIDE NOTE**
you dont need to do alot of stuff to decrease your game **performance!** be careful about this kinda coding!

Comment: Lerp will move object smoothly, but it will change it movement speed. (for small moves speed will be small and for bigger we'll see tremendous change) MoveTowards is better for me. But my main question was about ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition.x). That was the point where I get stuck.